# Need to slide my divs

Tags: jquery

im looking for something that make slider by divs .. i search for it and i found this :

The HTML :

```
<div class="mydivs">
    <div>divasdas 1</div>
    <div>divasdasdasdad 2</div>
    <div>divasdasdasdasdasd 3</div>
    <div>div 4asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div id="prev">go to previous div</div>
<div id="next">go to next div</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGkPV/1/)

but i have a small problem , i need the div`s slides every 2s. is that possible ?

Comment: Yes. It's possible...

Comment: @MarcB thanks buddy , waiting ur Code :D

Comment: We're not here to do your job for you. YOU write some code, we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: @MohamedSamy Do you means it's automatically sliding instead of button clicked?

Comment: @MarcB , i`m sorry man. i just tried to make it by myself and its not working . any way thanks for comments

Comment: @Felix i mean automatically sliding with the button also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to excute the "next slide" function every 2000 milliseconds.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    divs.hide().first().show();
    $("#next").click(NextSlide);
    $("#prev").click(PrevSlide);

    function NextSlide() {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show next
    }

    function PrevSlide() {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).show();
    }

    setInterval(NextSlide,2000);
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGkPV/54/)**

Comment: Good thing, but the `name` attr is deprecated in html5, is it not? so its just `$("#next")`, `$("#prev")` for slider buttons i think.

Comment: @АндрейПочекуев You're absolutely right. I just edited what was already in the fiddle without noticing. I edited my code and the fiddle now.

Comment: Thanks guys its working perfectly .. @Sadiq i change it for the begging :P